# Maven is not finding scala tests

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven

I have a scala test class but when I attempt to run using the Maven goal 'test'
the tests are not being run. I receive the Maven message "There are no tests to run." even though the tests are located in the scala test class. Do I need to add extra configuration ?

Here is my package setup :

[image]

Here is the output of the Maven "test" goal when run against the pom file :

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building scala.maven.test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources
>   (default-resources) @ scala.maven.test --- [WARNING] Using platform
>   encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is
>   platform dependent! [INFO] Copying 0 resource [INFO]  [INFO] ---
>   maven-scala-plugin:2.9.1:add-source (scala-compile-first) @
>   scala.maven.test --- [INFO] Add Source directory:
>   C:\workspaces\29112012\scala.maven.test\src\main\scala [INFO] Add Test
>   Source directory:
>   C:\workspaces\29112012\scala.maven.test\src\test\scala [INFO]  [INFO]
>   --- maven-scala-plugin:2.9.1:compile (scala-compile-first) @ scala.maven.test --- [ERROR]
>   C:\workspaces\29112012\scala.maven.test\src\main\java [ERROR]
>   C:\workspaces\29112012\scala.maven.test\src\main\scala [ERROR]
>   C:\workspaces\29112012\scala.maven.test\src\test\scala [INFO]
>   Compiling 2 source files to
>   C:\workspaces\29112012\scala.maven.test\target\classes [INFO]  [INFO]
>   --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ scala.maven.test --- [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to
>   date [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default)
>   @ scala.maven.test --- [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up
>   to date [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources
>   (default-testResources) @ scala.maven.test --- [WARNING] Using
>   platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e.
>   build is platform dependent! [INFO] Copying 0 resource [INFO]  [INFO]
>   --- maven-scala-plugin:2.9.1:testCompile (scala-test-compile) @ scala.maven.test --- [ERROR]
>   C:\workspaces\29112012\scala.maven.test\src\test\java [ERROR]
>   C:\workspaces\29112012\scala.maven.test\src\test\java..\scala [INFO]
>   Compiling 1 source files to
>   C:\workspaces\29112012\scala.maven.test\target\test-classes [INFO] 
>   [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:testCompile
>   (default-testCompile) @ scala.maven.test --- [INFO] Nothing to compile
>   - all classes are up to date [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.1:test (default-test) @ scala.maven.test ---
>   [INFO] Surefire report directory:
>   C:\workspaces\29112012\scala.maven.test\target\surefire-reports
>
> -------------------------------------------------------  T E S T S
>   ------------------------------------------------------- There are no tests to run.
>
> Results :
>
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
>
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 11.354s [INFO] Finished at: Fri Nov 30 16:57:05 GMT
>
> ### 2012 [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/17M [INFO]

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>scala.maven.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala.maven.test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.scala-tools
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-scala-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [2.9.1,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>                                    
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest_2.9.0-1</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.M5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>



</project>
```

Comment: What's your test class name? Maven can be pretty picky and by default I think it requires the class name to end in 'Test'. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072484/maven-wont-run-tests/11072557#11072557

Comment: @Noah yep, that fixed it. ive specified jUnit version 4.11 in my pom file so would have thought this should'nt matter ? if you put your comment into an answer I'll accept, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your test class name? Maven can be pretty picky and by default I think it requires the class name to end in 'Test'.

See my previos post:
[Maven won't run tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072484/maven-wont-run-tests/11072557#11072557)

Answer (score 4):

Even though this is a very late reply, but I wrote it hoping that someone might get benefitted from it in case their scala unit test are not getting discovered. One of the major and silent culprit is the absolute path to the test classes. If there is a space in the name of any directory on the path, scalatest won't pick it up. Rename such directories for successful running of unit tests.