# How to execute tests in a single class using pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

I have to execute tests in one class. so i added the fallowing code to my "pom.xml".

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/integration/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/integration/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/integration/reports/**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

under integration folder i have separate folders. So i need to execute the tests which are under reports folder. While executing this command "mvn clean -Dtest=ReportTest test".

```
Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

How to execute the tests, i need to change pom or execute command.

Answer (score 2):

To execute a Test Case (Test class) use the maven command (refer [Maven Single Test](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html))

**`mvn -Dtest=com.xxx.yyy.ReportTest test`** - use fully Qualified Name instead of Short Name.

if you are executing this maven command from Parent pom, that has two or more dependencies(modules) also append also append the **-DfailIfNoTests=false** argument to avoid test failures on other dependency modules.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this from test congiguration:

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>**/integration/**</exclude>
</excludes>
```

Also, by using `-Dtest=ReportTest` you attempt to run single test-class `ReportTest.java`, not all tests in `/reports` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You use the simple name of the class not the fully-qualified name of the class. So, if you have a test in `"org.testype.test.TestDemo"` and that is the only test you want to run, your command line would look like this:

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestDemo
```

Look at the link [Maven won't run tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072484/maven-wont-run-tests)